# How to test my ANOVA data analysis with Bayesian ABtesting?

Tags: rstudio, bayesian, anova, ab-testing

I have one application that behaves in 2 ways, lets call them Dynamic and Static. I run 2 experiments to check the difference between these 2 behaviors with 50 participants for each. Assume that I have the following results:

```
UID AppType Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
--------------------------
100 Dynamic 50  71  82  13
101 Static  68  98  12  78
103 Static  66  36  11  78
104 Dynamic 68  12  64  45
```

the number in Q1 to Q4 columns are the rating values (0 to 100) that users gave to some questions about the behavior of the system. I've compared the user's answers of each application (Dynamic and Static) per question in ANOVA test (so Q1 to Q4 separately) and it said that there is no significant difference between my Applications.

I have recently seen Bayesian AB test and I would like to check my data with this test, but I am not sure if it fits in my scenario and how i can use it with R Studio. I've seen [Frank Portmann](http://fportman.com/blog/bayesab-0-dot-7-0-plus-a-primer-on-priors/) blog, but honestly I couldn't set my data into the formulas!

I wonder if AB testing is just for checking different performance of web pages!! because whatever I've read about it were all about website performances!

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Few points: 1) bayesAB, just like ANOVA, is for single variate responses. You have a multivariate response, so it may be worth clarifying (edit your question) how you ran it through ANOVA. Did you multi-test or combine the values? 2) Unless you have some strong prior you plan to impose, bayesAB shouldn't show "significance" if ANOVA didn't - it should just give you posterior distributions that have close means. 3) This is probably a better question for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @merv, Thanks for the reply. 1) about the singe variable, lets say I want to compare each Q for dynamic and static systems separately. So they are not related as multi variable. 2) I know BayesAB would not show me a significant difference, but I want to see its interpretation as how much (percent) would the dynamic system perform better than static one, since there is a minor difference. 3) I've checked, but i couldn't find a good answer. Do you have any good simple reference?